# why is :else not (else) in clojure?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure you can write:

```
(cond (= 1 2) 1 
      :else 5)
```

In Scheme the equivalent would be:

```
(cond ((= 1 2) 1)
       (else 5))
```

The `:else 5` syntax is not as consistent as the `(else 5)`. What is the reason the else syntax is implemented in this seemingly inconsistent way in Clojure?

Comment: Thanks for all the nice answers. They all added value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think `(else 5)` is less consistent. `(cond ...)` arguments are stated as condition - value pairs. `:else value` is consistent because `:else` is just a convention - it works because `:else` is just an expression that's always true. There's no special rules for `:else` at all.

Answer (score 36):

`:else` is a actually a bit of a clever trick here:

- `cond` expects condition/value pairs - and :else is just a *value that is "truthy"* in Clojure so it guarantees that the condition is satisfied. (anything except null or false counts as "truth"). You could equally use ":donkey" as a guaranteed true condition value if you liked.
- However, :else also *conveys meaning to a human reader* (i.e. this condition is the one to be executed if none of the other conditions match

So really it's just a convention that works in `cond` expressions and is meaningful to human readers.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of reasons; primarily I think it's because `cond` is implemented as a macro around `if`.  On the other hand, in Scheme `else` is just a synonym for `t` in this context; it's not a function call, so why make it look like one?

Comment: How is the fact that `cond` is implemented as a macro relevant?

Comment: Because macros have a different syntax than functions.

Answer (score 3):

99% of the time, parens in Clojure imply a function or macro call.  This is in contrast to some other Lisps that use parens for grouping.  In Clojure, if grouping is necessary, e.g. in `fn` or `let` bindings, you will use `[]` instead.

Rich discusses part of the reasoning behind making this change in a recent interview [here](http://www.codequarterly.com/2011/rich-hickey/).  In short, it helps make code more immediately readable, because you don't have to spend time figuring out what parens represent.

Comment: but: it is valid clojure; it's just going to throw an exception